# Python3 json with japanese characters

Tags: python-3.x, python-unicode

I am using aws lambda to return a simple json with some Japanese characters.
I can't seem to get the characters to display correctly.
Here's what my code looks like:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

minutes = datetime.datetime.now().minute
status = ""

if minutes < 10:
    status = u"良好"
else:
    status = u"不良"

response = {}
response['ID'] = 1
response['Status'] = status

data = json.dumps(response, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
data = json.loads(data)

return data
```

The above code returns:

```
{"ID": 1, "Status": "\u4e0d\u826f"}
```

I have also tried this:

```
data = json.dumps(response, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8)
```

But to no avail.

How can I get the response to return japanese characters?

Edit:
One more thing I noticed. In the browser I get the above json output, however when running a test in AWS console I get the characters displayed properly. What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it your terminal's problem?

I got Japanese characters displayed correctly on my Mac terminal.

```
import json

minutes = 9
status = ""

if minutes < 10:
    status = u"良好"
else:
    status = u"不良"

response = {}
response['ID'] = 1
response['Status'] = status

data = json.dumps(response, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
data = json.loads(data)

print(data)
```

> {'ID': 1, 'Status': '良好'}

https://ideone.com/XZeVkS

Comment: Hmmm, could be. I am getting that output in a browser and when curling the api endpoint. I will try getting that in python or js and let you know.

Comment: It was my terminal, I asked a colleague and characters are displaying correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case you are running flask using the ensure_ascii did not fix the problem, you have to change disable it on the app level this way:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
```